# How can I create a 32-bit remote powershell session (on a 64-bit machine)?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, powershell

On a local 64-bit machine, I can open 'PowerShell (x86)'. But if I do 'Enter-PSSession' to another machine running a 64-bit OS, it creates a 64-bit PowerShell.

In my scenario I need a 32-bit PowerShell session. How can I get one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to use the `-ConfigurationName` parameter, like this:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell32
```

You can get the list of available configurations with:

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration
```

Note that the configurations are specific to the remote machine. In my quick tests, a 32-bit OS only has `Microsoft.PowerShell` which is 32-bit, while a 64-bit OS has `Microsoft-PowerShell` for 64-bit and `Microsoft-PowerShell32` for 32-bit.

Comment: Additionally, if Microsoft.PowerShell32 is not available on your 64bit machine you can register it using:
Register-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell32 -processorarchitecture x86 -force